# jQuery Select2 Tokenization - Only accept values are in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to use the Automatic tokenization example from here: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tokenizer

The point is that I can also type items that are not in the drop down (e.g.: yellow, orange, potato) and they got tokenized too.

Is there a way that only elements that are in the list get tokenized?

Lastly, is it possible to change the UI a bit so it doesn't grey out the selected options but they have a check icon instead (like in a multi-select dropdown)?

Note: I have no code at the moment but I am making my question based on following sample code: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/VeQGLO

This is the JS that is in the site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tokenizationSelect2").select2({
        placeholder: "Your favourite car", //placeholder
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: ['/',',',';'," "] 
    });
})
```

Comment: Please show your code - there is a way for what you are looking for, but its easier if I know what you did so far.

Comment: I have actually no code at the moment, just playing around with this sample I found on internet. http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/VeQGLO/ I will update my question though.

Answer (score 0):

Found your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30981409/1040225

```
createTag: function(params) {
            return undefined;
       }
```

... and set you up your codepen example with the solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egjEvm

Comment: I tried that but then if I copy and paste a list like this: "Bugatti,Ferrari,BMW,Lamborghini " it won't auto select things because it will treat everything as a single string.

Comment: Yes, the plugin has some issues with the user input, f.e. it also doesn't delete the full token when you try to delete with the backspace key of your keyboard. It is far from perfect, but in my (personal) opinion the most complete plugin out there. It would be possible to write a function to parse pasted strings, then again I don't really see the use case for it?

Comment: Well, in this case, the dropdown will have around 100 elements and we will like to: a) being able to copy and paste a comma separated list that allow you to preselect elements that are in the dropdown and b) not create new tags if the element doesn't exist.