# Selecting multiple items in Select2 but keep the searchbar empty

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

I am using the JS library [Select2](https://select2.org/)(4.0.5).

I want to be able to select multiple items in the drop down but keep the searchbar empty. I dont want select2 generating tags. I have tried setting the `tags` option to `false` and `multiple` to `true`. But it didnt work as intended. I also tried returning `undifiend` from the function `createTag`. but that too didnt work.

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471338/how-to-disable-creating-new-tags-with-select2-v4-0) on the subject.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/992996/)

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/en5jv31h/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable creating new tags with select2 v4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471338/how-to-disable-creating-new-tags-with-select2-v4-0)

Comment: @Justcode halfway yes, I want to be able to write in the searchbar aswell.

Comment: @SumeshTG That solution does not work form me, i linked to that post also.

Comment: @AllramEst Why ? Your question not clear.